# What's the meaning of 'it' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, dummy-pronouns

I am not sure about the meaning of **value it.**

Is this idiom-like expression? Or if not, what does *it* refer to?

> Giving gay and lesbian couples the same rights in a union - that would not dilute Mom and Dad's marriage, make it any less binding or strong. We so **value it that** we want to share it. '' # Matt Foreman, executive director of the National Gay and Lesbian Task Force, suggested conservative leaders cynically have embraced opposition to same-sex marriages as a " wedge issue " to advance a larger agenda.

Comment: Are you having trouble figuring out what the pronoun "it" refers to in the sentence? The word "value" is used in a common way that you could find in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

'It' refers to "Mom and Dad's marriage".

He's saying that gay and lesbian couples want to get married because they value marriage and want to share in this thing that they value by getting married themselves.